# silverlight blogs?

Tags: silverlight

With the asp.net MVC framework the blogs of the team members (Rob Conery, Phil Haack etc) really helped me on my way and made me feel comfortable the development was going in the right direction.
Is there something similar for Silverlight?

-Edit:
I would like to mention that I would like to find members of the dev team themselves.
Currently the support for Silverlight across OS and browser is just too poor to make me care and invest time in it.
But I would like to keep a spying eye out so I can start caring when the framework fulfils it's potentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thanks for the feedback already. Are
>   any of those actually part of the
>   Silverlight dev team?

Yes, Jesse Liberty is is a senior program manager for Microsoft Silverlight in the Silverlight Development Division.

Tim Heuer is a program manager for Microsoft Silverlight.

Mike Snow (Silverlight Tips of the Day) is a Senior SDET Lead on the Web Tools team at Microsoft.

Answer (score 7):

Method ~ of ~ failed by Tim Heuer:
http://feeds.timheuer.com/timheuer-silverlight

Jesse Liberty - Silverlight Geek:
[http://feeds.feedburner.com/JesseLiberty-SilverlightGeek](https://feeds.feedburner.com/JesseLiberty-SilverlightGeek)

Community Silverlight content:
[http://silverlight.net/blogs/community/rss.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20090813030220/http://silverlight.net/blogs/community/rss.aspx)

Silverlight Tips of the Day
[http://silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/default.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20090628120009/http://silverlight.net:80/blogs/msnow/default.aspx)

Podcasts:
[http://www.sparklingclient.com/](https://sparklingclient.com/)

Wynapse (Mining the Web for Silverlight so YOU don't have to):
[http://geekswithblogs.net/WynApseTechnicalMusings/Default.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20170226214423/http://www.geekswithblogs.net:80/WynApseTechnicalMusings/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Mike Taulty has a lot of silverlight content in his blog on a regular base : (has done a lot of silverlight screecasts )

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/rss.aspx

the same with Karl Shifflett: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com

Matthias Shapiro : http://www.designerwpf.com

Michael Sync : http://michaelsync.net/

Robby Ingebretsen : http://nerdplusart.com/

Ruurd Boeke: http://www.sitechno.com/Blog

at least this is some excerpt from my blog reader

Answer (score 1):

[Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/) the product manager of .NET Framework writes form time to time about Silverlight in his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/). He reports about new releases and the feature they come with it and sometimes he posts some really nice tutorials to give examples how to use these features.

But of course the blog's focus lies more on the whole .NET Framework as only on Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm already subscribed to ScottGu's blog as the ppl I mentioned before mostly report to him.
But his focus is not really what I'm looking for. I need something more focused.

Answer (score 1):

http://silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/05/05/silverlight-resources.aspx